# Code Contracts and MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, code-contracts

I have an MVVM project in C#, and I want to use code contracts in it.
So this is my scenario:
Interface:

```
public interface IC042_Model
{
    void Save(C042 entity);
    void Delete(C042 entity);
}
```

Then I have the abstract class for the contracts:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IC042_Model))]
internal abstract class C042_Model_Contracts : IC042_Model
{
    public void Save(C042 entity)
    {
        Contract.Requires(entity != null);
    }

    public void Delete(C042_CondicaoPagamento entity)
    {
        Contract.Requires(entity != null);
    }
}
```

In another project, my model implements the interface, and if I call 
    this.Save(null) 
in any method, an warning is generated.
In my ViewModel, if I call the same method above: this.Save(null), no warning is generated, but when I run the application the above line raises a Contract exception.

Is there anything wrong with my approach?

Thanks in advance.

I've made another example that I think it will be easier for everyone to understand:

I've created the following class in a class library project:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string TrimAfter(string value, string suffix)
    {
        Contract.Requires(suffix != (string)null);
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(suffix));
        Contract.Requires(value != null);

        var index = value.IndexOf(suffix);

        if (index < 0)
            return value;

        return value.Substring(0, index);
    }
}
```

When I call it from a WPF project like below:

```
CodeDigging.StringExtensions.TrimAfter(null, null);
```

I don't get a warning for the contracts not being fullfield.

That's my problem, I hope it gets clearer now.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: What is the specific warning you are receiving?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. My problem is that the static checking is not working when I call this.Save(null) in the ViewModel, just in the Model.

Comment: I copied from a code with much more stuff, so I've changed a few things to turn it more readable, where one reads c042 it should be entity.

Comment: How does the implementation of the class look like? Do you override Save and Delete? You might have to declare them virtual in your abstract base class. Or why is C042_Model_Contracts abstract after all?

Comment: The implementation is just adding and deleting the entity using Entity Framework. The problem is that when I call the method passing null in the model it shows the warning, but in the ViewModel it does not.

Comment: "In my ViewModel, if I call the same method above: this.Save(null)" -- so your ViewModel has a Save method that calls the model's Save method? If so, you need to restate the requirements in the ViewModel. Or did you mean model.Save(null)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the ContractClass attribute on the interface:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(C042_Model_Contracts)]
public interface IC042_Model 
{ 
    void Save(C042 entity); 
    void Delete(C042 entity); 
}
```

There is a good description about code contracts [here](http://devjourney.com/blog/code-contracts-part-5-abstract-types-and-interfaces/)

Comment: I added the attributes in both classes. As I said before, in the model the squiggly appears, but in my ViewModel don't.